# How to add auto respond from my basic bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, auto-responder

**index.js **

```
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once(Events.ClientReady, c => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setActivity("Menghancurkan Dunia");
  })

// Log in to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

How to add auto respond from my basic bot

example :

- User : Hai
- Bot : Halo

Comment: A reasonable person would find your profile as offensive because you have an Ad*lf Hitler profile picture, please have it removed.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it with the `messageCreate` event.

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if(message.toLowerCase().includes('hey')){
        message.reply({ content: 'Hai' })
    }

 })
```

This if reacts on all messages which contains „hey“ whether written in upper or lower case.